# Finding the page id

Tags: post-meta, page-specific-settings

I'm not sure if I'm blind here, but short of digging directly into the database tables, where would I find the database id for a post or a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs always show in links in admin area, like /wp-admin/post.php?post=**2164**&action=edit

There are also some plugins that simplify this, quick search came up with [Simply Show IDs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-show-ids/).

Comment: So clearly I'm blind then, or just didn't think before posting

Answer (score 0):

Also, the status bar at the bottom of your browser is usually a convenient place to note the id when hovering over a link from within the admin

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin that can do this (and one I use often) is "Reveal ID for admins" http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reveal-ids-for-wp-admin-25/

Answer (score 0):

If you're a code geek, you might want to add `<body <?php body_class('class-name'); ?>>` and your body tag will show the page-id

Comment: Sorry, no, that would not add the post ID.

Comment: Ops, sorry, I meant to type this `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` with reference to the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class